# How stable is the Apache HttpAsyncClient?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to implement a NIO based aws java client and was thinking of using the [HttpAsyncClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/index.html) but its in Alpha 3 stage. Does anyone have experience using the client under any kind of load? Also when can we expect it to go to beta and release?

Comment: Beta1 can be expected next week (there is an ongoing release vote). GA is likely sometime around May - July.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache HttpAsyncClient 4.0-beta1 was officially released yesterday. GA can be expected in three to four months.

As far as stability is concerned, since no one else responded, I can only give me my very biased opinion. HttpAsyncClient is based on HttpCore NIO which is reasonably well tested and is known to be capable of dealing with a great deal of load. HttpAsyncClient also re-uses a lot of high level protocol handling code from HttpClient. The amount of new code is not that great and can be expected to stabilize reasonably fast.